# prevObject returned when selecting an element

Tags: jquery-selectors

So I'm making some elements in my js file as follows:

```
grocerySpan = $("<span>").addClass("grocery").html(grocery.name).attr('id',"page"+groceriesIdCounter);
```

My first question is whether it is ok that I am assigning id as i did in the line above (using string concatenating)?

I have different spans made with each their own id, #page0, #page1..., now when I try selecting the a specific span as follows:

```
var tempGrocerySpan = $("span"+"#page"+groceriesIdCounter+".grocery");
```

I get a prevObject returned.

now here is a screenshot of my DOM from 
[chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM4wI.png)

As I read a prevObject means that the selector can't find the current element selected, but as I can see from chrome debugger my selecter and the element selector are the same, or am I overseeing something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $('span') rather than $('<span>')

Comment: I am making the elements in the first line of code, I dont see why it should be without <>.